# C# MVC3 DropDownList - No ID found in the form post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I just made a form containing a DropDownList, it perfectly shows the option names, but doesn't post the ID of the selected option into the controller.

Here is the code for the controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Insert(int id)
    {

            TemplateRepository repo = new TemplateRepository();
            List<Template> templateList = repo.ListAll().ToList<Template>();

            ViewData["Template"] = new SelectList(templateList, "Id", "Omschrijving");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult InsertOrEditSubmit(Klant klant)
        {
            KlantRepository repo = new KlantRepository();
            klant.Naam = Request["Naam"];
            klant.Adres = Request["Adres"];
            klant.Postcode = Request["Postcode"];
            klant.Woonplaats = Request["Woonplaats"];
            klant.Email = Request["Email"];
            klant.Telefoon = Request["Telefoon"];

            repo.SaveOrUpdate(klant);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

And here is the code in the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("InsertOrEditSubmit", "Klant", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.DevExpress().Label(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "label";
        settings.Text = "Template";
        settings.AssociatedControlName = "Template";
    }
).GetHtml() <br />
@Html.DropDownList("Template", ViewData["Template"] as SelectList);

@Html.DevExpress().Button(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
        settings.Name = "Insert";
        settings.Text = "Toevoegen";
        settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
    }
).GetHtml()
@Html.DevExpress().Button(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "button";
        settings.Name = "Cancel";
        settings.Text = "Terug";
        settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e){ document.location='" + DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "Gebruiker", Action = "Index" }) + "'; }";
    }
).GetHtml()
}
```

Hope someone can explain why it doesn't post the ID..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: Request["Template"];

Try a simple test:

(Controller)

```
ViewData["Test"] = new SelectList(new[] {new {Id = 1, Text = "Test 1"}, new {Id = 2, Text = "Test 2"}, new {Id = 3, Text = "Test 3"}}, "Id", "Text");
```

(View)

```
@Html.DropDownList("Test", ViewData["Test"] as SelectList)
```

Now the Request["Test"] should return the Id of the selected value.

But if your View is strongly-typed, in your case to the object "Klant", you don't need to fill the values with the Request, the object will be auto-populated and if your object have a property Template it'll be populated too.

Comment: If I try Request["Template"]; It gives me the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'DomainClasses.Domain.Template'.

Comment: In the controller I checked the posted data with quickview and the value at "Template" is defined as null.

Comment: Are you sure that your "templateList" has the field called "Id"?

Comment: Yups, When i check "repo.ListAll().ToList<Template>()" with quickwatch, it gives me 4 records, in those 4 recordes are base, naam and omschrijving, in base is the id defined. So I guess it should find the id right?

Comment: And that's what he puts in List<template> templateList.

Comment: Try a simple test:
ViewData["Test"] = new SelectList(new[] {new {Id = 1, Text = "Test 1"}, new {Id = 2, Text = "Test 2"}, new {Id = 3, Text = "Test 3"}}, "Id", "Text");

@Html.DropDownList("Test", ViewData["Test"] as SelectList)

Now the Request["Test"] should return the Id of the selected value.

Comment: I get this error: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Test'.

Comment: I've edit the answer to include the example for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that sometimes having a `name` along with the `id` for an input solves this issue.

What does your rendered html for the **Template** control look like?